# Convert Byte Array to String in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to generate MD5 of a string in my android code using kotlin..

```
val md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
val hash = md5.digest(queryToSign.toByteArray(Charset.defaultCharset())).toString()
```

But this gives me:

> [B@118072

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it.. Use BigInteger

```
val md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
val hash = BigInteger(1, md5.digest(queryToSign.toByteArray(Charset.defaultCharset()))).toString(16)
```

Comment: Otherwise using Hex converters (apache codex for example) will do the trick

Comment: For everyone: although it is a pretty-looking solution, BE AWARE all leading zeros will be TRIMMED. In case of calculating hash it is critical. So there must also be a code that checks the result's length and completes it with zeros if needed. For example, `val correctedHash = "0".repeat(bytes.size * 2 - hash.length) + hash`

Answer (score 0):

byteArrayOf(80,87,68).decodeToString()

= PWD

[click here to see how it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHp5V.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).