# Typecast String to ByteArray in kotlin

Tags: arrays, string, kotlin

I have variable in String format in kotlin:

```
var a ="[B@53c1c428"
```

I want to change it's datatype from String to `ByteArray` i.e typecast it to `ByteArray`, somewhat like:

```
var b: ByteArray = a
```

I also tried:

`var b = a as ByteArray`, but this throws an Exception

If I do:

`var b = a.toByteArray()`, I get output like:

```
[B@3aea9e4
```

But I want `[B@53c1c428` as `ByteArray`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That's a toString() representation of ByteArray (whilch is Byte[] in Java), you can't get your array back having only toString() representation.

Comment: Possibly you want to create string from byte array with `String(myByteArray)`.

Comment: "I want [B@53c1c428 as ByteArray" — what content do you expect that ByteArray to have after such cast? i.e. what would be the length of that ByteArray and what would be its elements?

Comment: In general, anytime you see something like `[B@3aea9e4`, what you have is meaningless.  You might be able to convert meaningless data into other meaningless data without errors, but that doesn't make it meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify:
`[B@53c1c428` is the hexadecimal hash code of that object with a `B[@` prefix. The string `"[B@53c1c428"` itself does not contain the data needed to reconstruct the `ByteArray`.

---

Consider this:

```
val str = "Test"
val byteArray = str.toByteArray()
println(Integer.toHexString(byteArray.hashCode())) // 1f32e575
println(byteArray) // [B@ + hash code as hexadecimal representation

val str2 = "This is a really long text and no 8 digit hex number in this world could encode it."
val byteArray2 = str2.toByteArray()
println(Integer.toHexString(byteArray2.hashCode())) // 279f2327
println(byteArray2) // [B@ + hash code as hexadecimal representation
```

---

`toByteArray()` already gives you a `ByteArray`. If you want to print the single digits as integers do it like this:

```
val str = "Test"
println(str.toByteArray().joinToString(" "){ "$it" })
```

Output:

> 84 101 115 116

This output would be enough to fully restore the `ByteArray`, because it contains all necessary information.

Comment: I get output something like:
91 66 64 53 51 99 49 99 52 50 56.
How do I convert it into format like:
[B@53c1c428 ?

Comment: @troy_achilies See my update: For example, make your ByteArray really long. Let's say 1024 kBytes. If you call toString() on it, the representation should have gotten longer, doesn't it? But it hasn't!

Comment: @troy_achilies why would you want that? Read the answer again. `[B` means: that object is a byte array. `@53c1c428` is the hashCode of the byte array. It's not the content of the byte array. If you call toString() on a byte array with 1 million values, you'll only get those few characters. It's obviously impossible to get back the million bytes from only those few characters.

Comment: But if I do this:

java.math.BigInteger(1,[B@53c1c428).toString(16), I get a legit String, It's not a refernce, I think.

Comment: @JBNizet I updated my answer regarding that it is not a reference but the hash code. thx

Comment: @troy_achilies it depends on what you mean by "legit" ;)

Comment: I get this:
"67481d54640fde669d533894890e8f4cef13a50fd9ad3992e3638b9407d9ce6200947b54f8f6a96c5df1c9d25d0d2c2bae4ce629840e55e844769b3ce98e4f2d".
It is hex String.

Comment: @troy_achilies that code does not even compile: java.math.BigInteger(1,[B@53c1c428).toString(16) ...

Comment: @WilliMentzel, check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597980/convert-byte-array-to-string-in-kotlin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180159/discussion-between-troy-achilies-and-willi-mentzel).

Comment: @troy_achilies see my updated answer. At no point is the string "[B@118072" used to restore the byte array! please debug/output the code in the thread you provided: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597980/convert-byte-array-to-string-in-kotlin